# Change button color as background color changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I created a fixed button with a partially transparent background which works great when displayed over a dark background but when I display it over a light background it is not visible.

I'd like it to be readable on both light and dark backgrounds, i.e. the button should change to a darker color when displayed on a light background and vice versa.

How can I code this in JavaScript?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain what you tried, add some code, show examples and explain the problem. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for learn how you can improve your question.

Comment: From what I understand you have a button that is declared in HTML and that has an RBGA background property, is that correct? There are ways that you can do that with JS or Sass / Less. Could you post your HTML / CSS before we start writing code?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using something like [TinyColor](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor) to detect if the background is light or dark and style the button appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to solve it using special CSS property. The best solution is to play with nested CSS classes. Something like:

**CSS**

```
.light-background {
   background: white;
}
.light-background button {
   background: gray;
   color: white;
}
.dark-background {
   background: gray;
}
.dark-background button {
   background: white;
   color: gray;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="light-background">
    <button>Light</button>
</div>
<div class="dark-background">
    <button>Dark</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bwd1mvwd/